# External Service in Login Flow for Community users

Tags: customer-community, loginflow, external-services

I'm trying to use the *External Services* feature to call a REST-based SMS API for the two-factor authentication of our Community users. (Basically recreating this scenario, but with an External Service instead of the Apex callout: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_3p_sms_2fa_login_flow.htm).

For this I have defined the OpenApi schema of the service, created the named credential, the service and the flow. And everything is working fine, when I debug the flow as an administrator.

But, when I set it up as a login flow for Community users, I get the error:

```
Error Occurred During Flow "SMSTwoFactorAuth": Action name not found: (...)__Service
```

The action name is the auto-generated Apex action for the External Service I can see in the Flow editor.

Is there any limitation of the External Services, that they cannot be used by Community users?
This auto-generated class does not appear in the regular classes list, so I can't e.g. add it to the list of class permissions for the community profile.

Comment: Hi Pawel, did you solve your problem? I'm experiencing similar problems now in our Partner Community with flows containing "External Services". If you managed to solve it, please help me too, I even put a bounty on my own question:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302837/flow-interrupted-on-action-external-service-in-partner-community

Comment: I went with custom Apex Invokable class in the end to bypass this issue, so I'm afraid I can't help.

Comment: Similar question (currently not solved): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/335596/external-service-call-in-a-visual-flow-from-guest-user

Answer (score 0):

Things might vary depending on whether you are using a real Login Flow, or a normal Flow on a Login page.
When you are running a Login Flow, then you are not yet authenticated.
So the user is, in fact, the Community's Guest User.

You need to give the following rights :

- Community Site : checking "Guest Access to the Support API" might be useful
- Guest User profile : "Run Flows" if it's a normal Flow
- Guest User profile : add your Flow to "Flow access" it it's a normal Flow
- Guest User profile : add named credential used in External Service to "Named Credential Access"
- if by any chance you had Apex classes (eg SF controllers in some Lightning Components in your Flow), you should also add them to your Guest User profile
- in a Login Flow, you might need to check "Render Flow in Lightning Runtime"

I hope this helps.