# External Service call in a Visual Flow from Guest User

Tags: visual-flows, guest-user, external-services

I have created a Visual Flow in Salesforce that performs an action that calls a configured External Service.
The flow correctly works in the debug mode (I am logged as system admin).

On the other hand, when I run the flow as a guest user (from the community) I receive the following error:
'***Error Occurred: Action name not found: null null null
Salesforce Error ID: 749420798-234946 (1825761591)***'

It seems that the External Service is not accessible by the guest user.

Could you kindly help me to solve this problem?

Comment: This is a GACK! You should get in touch with Salesforce support!

Comment: Similar issue, but was solved with an invocable action instead of an external service: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/273408/external-service-in-login-flow-for-community-users

Answer (score 1):

You may need to contact Salesforce, seems they are tracking as a known issue: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001nV7EQAU